# How do I fix this error that I get when I open my application made in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I made an app in android studio and it worked for me. I tried exporting the apk to test it and it worked. So far so good.

Then when I upload it to PlayStore, I install it and when I try to open it I can not and I miss an error that I enclose in a capture.

The part of the application code that I think gives an error is this:

```
 dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'


    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.11.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'

}
```

This is the build.gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    //the compression of webp file during build causes problem with FileDescriptor in ContentProvider.
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "webp"
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shstickers.shstickers"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 17
        versionName "1.27"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        def contentProviderAuthority = applicationId + ".stickercontentprovider"
        // Creates a placeholder property to use in the manifest.
        manifestPlaceholders =
                [contentProviderAuthority: contentProviderAuthority]
        // Adds a new field for the authority to the BuildConfig class.
        buildConfigField("String",
                "CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY",
                "\"${contentProviderAuthority}\"")
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

task checkDebug {
    doLast {
        println("checkDebug")
        if (android.defaultConfig.applicationId.startsWith("com.whatsapp")) {
            throw new GradleException("applicationId in defaultConfig cannot start with com.whatsapp, please change your applicationId in app/build.gradle");
        }
        checkApplicationIdInDebug()
    }
}

private void checkApplicationIdInDebug() {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    def ignoreApplicationIdCheck = properties.getProperty('ignoreApplicationIdCheck')
    if (ignoreApplicationIdCheck == null) {
        if (android.defaultConfig.applicationId.equals("com.example.samplestickerapp")) {
            throw new GradleException("Your applicationId is currently com.example.samplestickerapp, please change your applicationId to a different string in app/build.gradle in line 16");
        }
    } else {
        println("application id check ignored")
    }
}

task checkRelease {
    doLast {
        println("checkRelease")
        if (android.defaultConfig.applicationId.startsWith("com.example")) {
            throw new GradleException("applicationId in defaultConfig cannot start with com.example, please change your applicationId in app/build.gradle");
        }
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    println(task.name)
    if (task.name.contains("assembleDebug")) {
        task.dependsOn checkDebug
    }
    if (task.name.contains("assembleRelease")) {
        task.dependsOn checkRelease
    }
}

    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'


    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.11.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'

}
```

Any idea how to fix it? The error that appears when you open the app on your mobile device after installing it is attached as a capture.

[image: Error that exits when trying to open the application once installed on the mobile]

Comment: I would double check the release APK to make sure it has all of the JNI libraries. APKs are just zip files. You should also edit your post to include what device/OS version where you are getting the error.

Comment: How do I put the library "libstatic-webp.so" in / system / lib.
And how do I put the library "libnativeloader.so" in / system / lib64

Comment: Gradle should be doing that. So either there is a problem in your build script, or an issue with the libraries you are using. I found this fresco issue: [When building via App Bundle, Fresco fails to find "libimagepipeline.so"](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/2253) which seems similar but would check how you've configured the build cache. If you are stuck, recommend [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54392091/edit) your post to include your build.gradle and what you've tried.

Comment: I have already published my publication and I have added my build.grade. Any solution?